# .overwritePermissions() cant deny CONNECT to @everyone

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command that creates a channel then denys people the ability to speak in it. Here is the code:

```js
const bots = await channels.create('Bots: ', {
    reason: 'Created the total bots display channel.',
    type: 'voice',
    parent: parent
});

bots.overwritePermissions([
    {
        id: message.guild.id,
        deny: ['CONNECT']
    },
    {
        id: message.guild.id,
        allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
    }
]);
```

Everything works, the channel creates, it is under the correct parent, and everything. The only problem is that it doesn't deny 'CONNECT' to everyone. The strange thing is it does allow 'VIEW_CHANNEL'. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `allow` and `deny` in one single Object if it's for the same ID. More information can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/OverwriteData).
Please try doing the following:

```js
const bots = await channels.create('Bots: ', {
    reason: 'Created the total bots display channel.',
    type: 'voice',
    parent: parent
});

bots.overwritePermissions([{
    id: message.guild.id,
    deny: ['CONNECT'],
    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you this works! One thing, like I said in the post I want to change the permissions for @everyone. the @everyone role ID is the guild id. That is why I did `message.guild.id`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I've changed this in my post @MichaelManders